# not able to click the hyperlink in a table through selenium python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate something using selenium webdriver python. I was partially successful in doing so.I got struck up in between.

```html
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="6563378117093014222" aria-describedby="devices_x1AccountId">
  <a href="accountSummary?accountId=6563378117093014222">6563378117093014222</a>
</td>
```

I am trying to click the hyperlink inside the table descriptor but its showing some error.

Here is my code:

```
deviceID = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@aria-describedby= 'devices_billingId']/a")
deviceID.click()
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please suggest some solution

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: @Rajesh you might search for the wrong aria-describedby -> see my updated answer

Comment: @drkthng its a typo. Even i have another scenario where i am using the 'devices_x1AccountId'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`

then in your xpath you are searching for "devices_billingId" but in your code the aria-describedby is "devices_x1AccountId"

```
deviceID = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@aria-describedby= 'devices_x1AccountId']/a")
deviceID.click()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'. I tried using find_element as well its not working :(

Comment: @Rajesh, `find_element` should return a `WebElement`, not a `list`. you are doing something else wrong.  @drkthng is absolutely correct.

Comment: I am getting error "unable to find the element" after changing it to find_element

Comment: I have a query whether the Xpath which i have given is proper?

Comment: @Rajesh No, if you are trying to find an element with the `aria-describedby` field set to `devices_x1AccountId`. In your xpath you are looking for `devices_billingId`.